# Parsing Error when adding Bootstrap to Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs3

I would like to add bootstrap to my Vue 3 project. I added bootstrap through typing
`cd <my-app>` then `vue add bootstrap-vue`. After i have installed bootsrap i get an error in terminal telling me that i have an `Parsing error: Unexpected token (10:4)` and `Declaration or statement expected.` this error seems to occur in my vue.confiq.js file, where i have an red sqiggle. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image: parsing error bootstrap vue 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your css object is outside your config? From the looks of it, it should rather be inside the defineConfig.

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {},
      scss: {},
    }
  }
});
```